# Can there be a full Fourier series on range $0<x<L$?

Tags: fourier-series

I am stuck at this problem:

Compute the Fourier Series for the function $x^2$ on the interval
$0<x<L$ using as a basis of function with boundary conditions $u'(0)=0$ and $u'(L)=0$. Sketch the partial sums of the series for $1,2,3$ terms.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck at? This is a fairly straightforward integral?

Comment: Am i supposed to find a half range series? can there be a full range series on half interval?

Comment: You can find the series for $x^2$ on $[-L,L]$, the $\sin$ terms will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you find a Fourier series for $x \mapsto x^2$ on $[-L,L]$ then since
the function is even, the series will only contain terms of the form
$\cos (n \pi {x \over L})$ terms.

The derivatives of the $\cos$ terms are $-n \pi { 1\over L} \sin (n \pi {x \over L})$ which are zero at $x=0,L$ as required.

The series will converge pointwise everywhere (since the function is Lipschitz).

Comment: ok. thanks a lot mate.